# How to run it blocks in parallel in protractor?

Tags: npm, jasmine, protractor

My *spec* file covers 50 different test cases for a specific test scenario. Each test case is covered in individual *it* block. The spec file takes 2 hrs to execute. I want to categorize *it* blocks in a way so that they run in parallel in multiple browser instances. For e.g. it should run like (5 *it* blocks * 10 browser instances) in parallel. I don't want to divide the *spec* file in different parts. Is there any alternate solution?

Comment: --grep flag allows you to run individual it blocks (protractor conf.js --grep='tagName') but it doesn't solve the purpose of parallel execution.

Comment: I have also tried to use parallel-protractor (https://www.npmjs.com/package/parallel-protractor) dependency but getting error:
path.js:7
    throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path));
    ^
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined

Answer (score 4):

When you decide to execute your test cases, use any configuration listed below. Please refer a typical `conf.js` file and choose any of the configuration in conf.js file.

```
exports.config = {

  // The address of a running selenium server.
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  specs: ['spec1.js','spec2.js']

};
```

> Type-1: Single browser instance : start one browser instance at a
>   time.

example configuration in the conf.js file.

```
capabilities: {
     browserName: 'chrome',
 },
specs: ['spec1.js','spec2.js']
```

The above configuration will launch chrome browser instance and executes all specs one by one

```
sequestial --> [chrome] --> spec1.js --> spec2.js
```

> Type-2: Different browser instance will launch in parallel and all the
>   specs which is mensioned in the `spec:[]` tag will execute in each
>   browser's instance separately.

example configuration in the conf.js file.

```
multiCapabilities: [
     { browserName: 'chrome', },
     { browserName: 'firefox', },
 ],
specs: ['spec1.js','spec2.js','spec3.js']
```

The above configuration will launch chrome, firefox browsers and executes all specs in each browser instance parallel.

```
         --> [chrome]  ---|--> spec1.js --> spec2.js --> spec3.js
         |                
       parallel           
         |
         --> [firefox] ---|--> spec1.js --> spec2.js --> spec3.js
```

> Type - 3: The below configuration will help you to execute different
>   set of specs in different browser instances.

example configuration in the conf.js file.

```
multiCapabilities: [
    { 
        browserName: 'chrome', 
        specs:['spec1.js']
    },
    { 
        browserName: 'firefox', 
        specs:['spec2.js'] 
    },
],
```

The above configuration will launch chrome, firefox browsers and executes `spec1.js` in chrome and `spec2.js` in firefox instances

```
         --> [chrome]  ---|--> spec1.js
         |                
       parallel           
         |
         --> [firefox] ---|--> spec2.js
```

> Type - 4: Execute different spec files in parallel with same browser.
>
> Consider you have 5 spec files in your test suit and you want to
>   execute everything in parallel. The below configuration will help you
>   to do that.

example configuration in the conf.js file.

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    specs: [
        'spec1.js', 'spec2.js', 'spec3.js' , 'spec4.js' , 'spec5.js'
    ],
    maxInstances : 5,
    shardTestFiles: true
}
```

The above configuration will launch 5 chrome instances and each spec will execute in those 5 chrome instances in parallel.

```
                             |-- [instance 1] --|--> spec1.js
                             |-- [instance 2] --|--> spec2.js
             --> [chrome] ---|-- [instance 3] --|--> spec3.js
                             |-- [instance 4] --|--> spec4.js
                             |-- [instance 5] --|--> spec5.js
```

The `maxInstances` number represents the maximum amount of browser windows that Protractor is allowed to create.

For example, with maxInstances set to 10, a test suite of 200 tests would result in Protractor creating 10 Chrome instances with each instance running 20 tests, whereas without shardTestFiles this would be one Chrome instance running all 200 tests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this solution is applicable at spec level. I am looking for an alternative so that I just need to group individual it blocks to run in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

You are unable to run "it" blocks parallel from within the same spec file.  The alternate solution would be to divide up your spec file such as `spec1.js`, `spec2.js`, and`spec3.js`

You would then add this to your conf.js file

```
specs:['filePath/spec1.js','filePath/spec2.js','filePath/spec3.js'],
capabilities: {
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 5 //set this to amount you want running at once
}
```

The `specs` param will accept arrays, or you can use wildcards such as `filePath/*.js` which would run all .js files within that folder (Make sure they are are protractor test cases)

`maxInstances` will be set to the amount running at once. I find it easier to use headless mode when running multiple instances at once, for chrome the option looks like:

```
chromeOptions: {
        args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1080"]
}
```

Comment: This solution is applicable at spec level and is a common solution. I am looking for an alternative so that I just need to group individual it blocks to run in parallel.

Comment: @Mayank This appears to be a feature request for what you want in the repo right now https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/569 Might want to watch that, when(if) it gets implemented, that might solve your problem